# how to use expect inside shell script

Tags: shell, expect

> I have a bash+expect script which has to connect normal user, i want
>   to read the  specific file and store into the variable to be used
>   after while that specific file in root user. How can i get the value ?
>   My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
set prompt ">>> "
set command ls /root/test1

expect << EOF
spawn su root
expect "password:"
send "rootroot\r"
expect "$prompt\r"
send "$command\r"
expect "$prompt\r"
expect -re "(.*)\r\n$prompt\r\n"
EOF

echo "$command"

 if [ ! -f "$command" ]; then

                echo "file is not exist"
else
                echo "file is exist"
            fi
```

> whenever i'm execute my shell script it show following output:
>
> ls: /root/: Permission denied
>
> file is not exist
>
> basically test is there but it is showing "file is not exist"

Comment: Are you sure that your shell became successful on getting root access?

Comment: It is connecting successfully to root  but i'm not able to read or write there.

Comment: You have tcl `set` commands in a bash script. Given what you show, the $prompt and $command shell variables are both unset.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very old but i hope someone gets help from this answer.

--> You should use `#!/usr/bin/expect` or `#!/bin/expect` to use `expect` properly, `expect<<EOF` might work but thats not conventional way to write script.

--> You script should end with `EOF` statement . Ex.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect << EOF
<some stuff you want to do>
EOF
```

--> Some basic thing about `spawn`. Whatever you write in `spawn` will execute but it will not have effect on entire script. Its not like environment variables.

In short, **`spawn` will start new process and your command is not under spawn process.**
Ex.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn bash -c "su root '<your-cmd-as-root>'"
<some-expect-send-stuff-etc>
```

Now in your script, `$command` should be write inside `spawn` like i showed in above example.